Ehresmann connections on general G-bundles?
There are two definitions of connections on bundles in terms of horizontal bundles:

In the case of a principal $G$-bundle $P$, a connection is a subbundle $HP<TP$ such that $HP\oplus VP=TP$ and it is $G$-equivariant in the sense that the derivative of the right $G$-action on $P$ maps $H_pP$ to $H_{p\cdot g}P$.
In the case of a general fiber bundle $E$, a connection is just a choice of $HE<TE$ with no equivariance condition (according to Kolář et al at least).

But what if my general bundle has a $G$-structure on it? For example on a Riemannian bundle presumably I would need to pick $HE$ in such a way that the induced parallel transport preserves orthonormal frames. But how do I do this directly in the definition? The naive idea that $HP$ has to be equivariant under automorphisms of the $G$-structure appears to be the exact opposite of what I need: e.g. an $\{e\}$-structure should have very few compatible connections, whereas any connection is $\{e\}$-invariant.

It depends on what you mean by $G$-structure. If you mean, a bundle with a $G$ action, then of course the natural definition would be a $G$-invariant connection. If you mean a bundle $E$ with a reduction of structure from $\mathrm{Diff}(F)$ to some Lie group $G$ (as is the case for a Riemannian bundle with reduction from $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\mathrm{O}(n)$) then the natural notion would be an Ehresmann connection on the associated principal $G$ bundle, which of course induces one on $E$.

@J.V.Gaiter I mean the latter. Of course I'm aware of the association process but I was hoping to come up with a general definition that doesn't rely on it.

The principal bundle associated to a bundle in some sense tells you how you're allowed identify fibers in a way compatible with your group action. It is tailor made for the kind of thing you're trying to do!
